# Creating, building and running MAUI .NET7.0 sample app using dotnet CLI on MS Windows 10

Tags: .net, windows, command-line-interface, maui, .net-7.0

I have MS Windows 10 (v.21H2, build 19044.2251) system with .NET 7.0 SDK and MS Visual Studio 2022 17.4.0 installed and I can create and run a MAUI default sample project from within VS2022.

Now I wanted to create, compile, build and run a sample .NET 7.0 MAUI app as an MS Windows app using `dotnet CLI` similar to [.NET MAUI with .NET CLI (Command Line Interface)](https://mauiman.dev/maui_cli_commandlineinterface.html) but for MS Windows.

By running

```
dotnet new maui
```

I'm getting a corrrect MAUI project and solution (I can copy it and build/run it from within VS2022).

What should be the second `dotnet CLI` command line to build and to run this MAUI sample project

```
dotnet build -t:??? -f net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0(?)  ...
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that we couldn't use dotnet cli to build .net maui app targeted on Windows currently. A related discussion on Github can be seen : [*How to run MAUI on Windows from command line?*](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/7490). You could join them for discussion.

**However**, good news is that reference to this Github issue : [*Build Windows target using dotnet build instead of msbuild.exe*](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3926) , we could use the **MSBuild** command instead of **dotnet build** command to build the MAUI application. Try the following command :

```
msbuild -r -p:Configuration=Release -p:RestorePackages=false -p:TargetFramework=net7.0-windows10.0.19041
```

Hope my answer could help you.